# Doxygen: How to link to tabs such as "Related Pages"?

Tags: html, markdown, doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 to generate HTML output from C/C++ header files. I have a `mainpage.md` markdown document for the main page. I'd like to explain on the main page what the various tabs such as "Related Pages" or "Modules" contain, and I'd like to have a link to them in `mainpage.md`.

Right now, I do that with the following markdown (in `mainpage.md`):

```
The [Modules](modules.html) tab ...
```

This works for HTML output, because the HTML output for the main page is `html/index.html` (the content of `mainpage.md` is embedded into that file), and the generated Modules page is `html/modules.html`, i.e. in the same output directory.

However, that does not work for other types of output (which I'd also like to support at some point).

My question is: How can the tabs such as "Related Pages" or "Modules" be linked to in the main page markdown in such a way that it works for all output formats?

Andy